# PowerShell - showing a message on remote computer screen

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

When I am running commands or installing software remotely using PowerShell - Invoke-Command etc I would like sometimes to be able to show a message on the remote screen so the user knows something is happening, or when work done etc.

I would like to if possible make this message look as professional as possible, e.g. better than just a standard winform message box if it can be done?  perhaps more the style of the Windows 10 ones with coloured background and use of image if possible.

Spent a while googling but most seem to relate to using obsolete methods such as net-send or using msg.exe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-show-a-messagebox/

So the issue really isnt creating the messagebox itself, its having it show on the users session.

So when you run a command against a system, youre using your creds to run the command therefore it wont show in  the users session. You can get around this by running it in the users context using a task scheduler. I have a script that does all this for you but, id hate to recreate the wheel and will have to wait till monday (when im at work) to post it here.

It accepts user input in your sessions that outputs it to a vbs, which then copies it over the message to the users machine, and a task schedule is set to run immediately for the user thats logged in.

edit: The script is this without the task scheduler. I just invoke `gwmi win32_computersystem | Select -ExpandProperty username` to get the current user logged in and add it to the task.

```
#Prompt for messge
$strMSG = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter message"

#deleting vbs if it exists
del C:\brief\test.vbs

#creating vbs from scratch so it doesnt override
New-Item C:\brief\test.vbs

#Appending each the values to a seperate line
Add-Content C:\brief\test.vbs 'Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")' 
Add-Content C:\brief\test.vbs "strText = `"$strMSG`"" 
Add-Content C:\brief\test.vbs 'intButton = objShell.Popup(strText,0,"Computer Support",48)'

#calling on the script
& cscript C:\brief\test.vbs
```

Comment: Thanks Abraham - that is an interesting way to do it, will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Found a great solution here which appears on quick testing to work well for displaying a toast notification on a remote machine

https://smsagent.blog/2019/06/11/just-for-fun-send-a-remote-toast-notification/